# Cassandra Error: Clustering column "domain" cannot be restricted (preceding column "timestamp" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)

Tags: cassandra, cql, database, nosql

I'm playing with Cassandra(cql). When I do a SELECT it returns me an error:

> Clustering column "domain" cannot be restricted (preceding column "timestamp" is restricted by a non-EQ relation).

Columns "domain" (type varchar) and "timestamp" (type timestamp) are Primary Keys.

WHEN I filter only by "timestamp" like this:

```
SELECT id, comment, language, location, section, domain, type, user, timestamp 
    FROM comments WHERE ts >= ? AND  ts <= ? ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Works fine, but when I try to filter including "domain" returns me that error:

```
SELECT id, comment, language, location, section, domain, type, user, timestamp 
    FROM comments WHERE domain=? AND ts >= ? AND  ts <= ? ALLOW FILTERING;
```

CREATE TABLE CQL:

```
CREATE TABLE table  ( 
id varchar,
type varchar,
section varchar,
comment text,
language varchar,
location text,
user int,
domain varchar,
timestamp timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY (id, timestamp, domain, user, section))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);
```

Comment: Have you looked at [official documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html) about `WHERE` limitations in Cassandra? It clearly states that range queries can be only at the last portion of the WHERE clause, and the error says that you are using `ts` in non restricted way. By the way the error says **Clustering column**, probably you have underestimate something in your table definition (eg partition key, clustering key). Post it and let's see...

Comment: This is my table definition.
`CREATE TABLE table  ( id varchar, type varchar, section varchar, comment text, language varchar, location text, user int, domain varchar,timestamp timestamp, PRIMARY KEY (id,timestampdomain,user,section)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important to note, but with Cassandra you need to take a query-centric approach to data modeling.  Essentially, if this is the query you need to support:

```
SELECT id, comment, language, location, section, domain, type, user, timestamp 
    FROM comments WHERE domain=? AND timestamp >= ? AND  timestamp <= ?;
```

Then your PRIMARY KEY should be designed to support that:

```
PRIMARY KEY (domain, timestamp, user, section, id))
```

As you won't be querying on `id`, it doesn't make sense to have it as your partitioning key (the left-most key in the PRIMARY KEY definition).  But you might still want it to be a part of the key, to help ensure uniqueness.

Notes:

- Queries with `ALLOW FILTERING` are terrible for performance, and should *NEVER* be used on a production system.
- This solution assumes that the cardinality of `domain` to `id` isn't infinite (which is probably is).  To get ahead of the potential for unbound row growth on your partitions, you may want to "bucket" your partition key by compositing `domain` with something else.